# How to Find Multiple Minima of Objective Function with Genetic Algorithm?

Tags: matlab, mathematical-optimization, genetic-algorithm

When using genetic algorithm to find global minimum of objective function, algorithm gives only the best result (smallest value of objective function).

Is it possible for genetic algorithm to give multiple best local minima it found? In my problem, I would like to get approximately best 100 results and to sort them by the value of objective function.

I couldn't find this option on MathWorks instruction site.

Comment: Local minima in math sense, where grad f=0? You know that GA does not guarantee that you get even one because it does not evaluate gradient in the best found point, do not you? You may try to accumulate all evaluated points, fix some distance parameter `r`, get the best, filter all points that are closer to it than `r`, select best from other, filter, repeat. For a more accurate multiple local minima search you need a gradient base approach supplemented with multi-start or basin-hopping.

Comment: Yeah, I do know. It is a numerical, derivative free method with drawbacks you've listed. I did get some nice results with Levenberg Marquardt method though, which is based on gradient/deriivative.

Comment: I will not be able to use gradient based methods in 2nd part of optimization because objective function in 2nd part is not differentiable by model parameters. Also, my main question still isn't answered and that is how to obtain more results from GA in Matlab? It only gives the best result.

Comment: In objective function code, you can store all evaluate points in global var `function fun(x)
global evals
evals(end+1) = x`, then, after you call `ga(fun`, you can process `evals` on your own way.